# Trying to save output of display(Math('f(x) = x + 2C')) to an image file using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, image, math, jupyter-notebook, export

I have learned how to display symbolic math in jupyter notebook using the display, Math, & Latex packages.

An example would be: `display(Math('some math eqn'))`, which would result in clearly formatted symbolic math within jupyter notebook.

Now I am interested in exporting the display to an image file so I can use it elsewhere.

I tried using the code below, but it returned a `NoneType` object: 
`Image(display(Math('f(x) = x + 2C')), embed=True, format=PNG)`

How would I go about doing this please?

Update:
I tried executing `display(Math("\dfrac{5x}{3}"))` via a cmd prompt and got this: `<IPython.core.display.Math object>`. I'm wondering if there's a way to convert this object type to an image?

Comment: You may be able to take a screen capture of your notebook then edit out the unwanted parts. You could also use a snipping tool to capture only the desired part. Both those tools are available in Windows 10 and you should be able to get utilities to do that for any operating system. The snipping tool is what I use for my own work.

Comment: That's what I've been doing thus far but I was hoping for a cleaner way of doing it.